# use java speech api or matlab for writing a tts

Tags: java, api, matlab, speech

I am working on a project about TTS. I have some modules written in matlab and some others in cpp. I should make an interface (like screen reader) and also use the matlab and cpp codes to prepare a complete TTS. I have just heard about java speech api and found it helpful, but to use this api I should convert these codes into java. 
Does anyone has any idea about choosing matlab or java for implementation, I mean java speech api can be better than matlab?

I appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Java Speech API doesn't technically do anything, as far as I can tell. It's an interface which other software may implement. I suggest using [CMU Sphinx 4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/), which is an implementation of it. It comes with lots of demos and is easy to install, plus there are helpful forums and it's open source. I don't know what your project is, but if you would like to implement really low level stuff (like your own Fourier transform or something) you can implement the Sphinx [DataProcessor](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/javadoc/edu/cmu/sphinx/frontend/DataProcessor.html) API and plug it in without having to create an entire system yourself. Then you'd just put your class in the configuration file, similar to this:

```
<component name="frontEnd" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.FrontEnd">
    <propertylist name="pipeline">
        <item>microphone </item>
        <item>premphasizer </item>
        <item>windower </item>
        <item>myfft </item>
        <item>melFilterBank </item>
        <item>dct </item>
        <item>liveCMN </item>
        <item>featureExtraction </item>
    </propertylist>
</component>
<component name="myfft" 
        type="my.stuff.fastFourierTransform"/>
```

If you have existing matlab code you can convert it into java classes using [this](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/). If you have cpp code that you'd like to use, you can use the [Java native interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).